# Malloc on char *arr[]

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

I am trying to hold a variable number of strings each with a max of 30 characters.

This is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 30

int main(void)
{
  int N=0;
  char *buff[MAX_SIZE];

  if(scanf("%d",&N)!=1)
  {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  *buff=malloc(N*sizeof(char**));

  /* ... code ... */

  strcpy(buff[0],"hello");

  puts(buff[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

Am I allocating memory correctly?

I haven't found anything similar, only that buff is an array of pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
char *buff[MAX_SIZE];

*buff=malloc(N*sizeof(char**));
```

you are declaring an array of `MAX_SIZE` (30) pointers to char, so potentially 30 strings (and not `N`). Then you are assigning to its first element `buff[0]` a pointer to a memory area containing N `char *` pointers.

That's not what you want.

If you need N strings, you need to allocate N pointers to char each able to contain `MAX_SIZE` characters.

1. First you need to allocate the array:

   ```
    char ** buff = malloc(N*sizeof(char *));
   ```

   Please note how the result of the malloc is assigned to `buff` and not to `*buff` like in your attempt. `buff` is basically an array of `char *` (that are strings), and each of them can be accessed through `buff[i]`, with `i` < N.
2. But all these pointers are still invalid (they still point to an undefined memory location as they are not initialized, yet), so you have to allocate all the strings:

   ```
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        buff[i] = malloc(MAX_SIZE);
   ```

   It could also be `malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char))`, but `sizeof(char)` is 1.

In every string you can store up to `MAX_SIZE-1` characters, because one of them will be occupied by the string terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: Alternatively: `char (*buff)[MAX_SIZE] = malloc(N*sizeof(char[30]));`, and then you have a lot fewer allocations to deal with

Answer (score 1):

As you've pointed out, what you have here:

```
char *buff[MAX_SIZE];//an array of MAX_SIZE pointers
```

is an array of pointers, each of which needs memory before writing to it.  To illustrate:

```
buff[0]
buff[1]
...
buff[MAX_SIZE-1]
```

But from what you have described, you want `N` strings, so

```
char *buff[N];
     |     |_This should represent number of strings
     |_This will be allocated to accommodate length of each string

buff[0]
buff[1]
...
buff[N-1]
```

Is more in-line with what you have described.

Now, (using perhaps a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)) for the pointer declaration, allocate each pointer with `MAX_SIZE` memory:

```
    //scanf N from user input
    char *buff[N];//this is a VLA
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        buff[i] = malloc(MAX_SIZE);//here is sizeof char (1) * SIZE_MAX
    }
    ...//use buff, then free buff (all N of them)
```